# showframe: how to define thickness of frame lines?

Tags: miktex2.9, showframe

Till to the last upgrade of MiKTeX (to 21.6) the following MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

Now, after upgrade it throw errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \ShowFrameLinethickness undefined.
```

and

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \ShowFrameColor undefined.
```

What is changed in the recent MiKTeX that those commands now are undefined? Do anyone know workaround which gives/return functionality of those commands, i.e. how to define thickness and color of `showframe` lines?

Comment: It seems there's currently a reorganisation of the packages (in particular packages documentation and packages source are now being two MiKTeX packages), and seeing your question, I checked on my system and saw `showframe` was no more installed, so I reinstalled it with the package manager – but for now there's no documentation. I think it will be uploaded soon.

Comment: @Bernard, this reorganization broke all my links to documentation. Now I observe, that some packages are installed twice (in different maps), so it seems that I need to wait to next iteration of MiKTeX upgrade or simple reinstall it after while ...

Comment: That’s not the only thing that seems broken. I’m using a fully updated TeX Live, and in the past I could use `showframe` with the `leaflet` document class, but not now. No error message, but the frame just doesn’t show.

Comment: Which version of `showframe` are you using? Moreover, if `showframe.sty` is successfully loaded, then you can find its full path on disk in the log, and open and check its contents.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, in `showframe.sty` is declared `\ProvidesPackage{showframe}[2002/11/10 v0.1f showframe (new impl., RN)] `, i.e. it is quite old (20 years).

Comment: Then MikTeX might have some problem fetching the latest version of `showframe`, which is `2020/10/14 v0.1j`. I suggest to report this to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging.

Comment: From the [svn repo of texlive](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/showframe.sty?r1=16240&r2=21515&pathrev=56658), macros `\ShowFrameLinethickness` and `\ShowFrameColor` were added in `showframe 2011/02/24 v0.1i`. (That link also provides info about how to implement these two macros, just as a short-term workaround. Or you could download the [latest `showframe.sty`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/showframe.sty?view=co)) Therefore the issue is that MikTeX suddenly reverted `showframe.sty` to its very first version.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, thank you very, very much for help. With recent version of `showframe` it works as before. Please, be so kind in convert your comments to an answer, that I can accept it and by it indicate that problem is solved :-)

Comment: Answered. BTW, an adapted question title might be more helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer is just a rewording from comments under the question.)

Somehow, MikTeX reverted `showframe.sty` to an quite old version (`2002/11/10 v0.1f`, compared to the latest `2011/02/24 v0.1i`) that the two macros `\ShowFrameLinethickness` and `\ShowFrameColor` were not even provided at that time. This is a MikTeX issue so I suggest to report it to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging.

As a short-term workaround, one can get the latest version of `showframe.sty` from either [CTAN](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/showframe.sty) or [texlive](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/showframe.sty?view=co). And then move it to the directory of the main/root tex file.